# How does Magento 2 Search work with '-'?

Tags: magento2, search

I have 4 products in catalog with names:

aaa

bbb

aaa-bbb

aaa_bbb

When I try to search "aaa", I get aaa, aaa-bbb and aaa_bbb products as a result (**screen 1**) 
[image: screen 1]

When my query is "bbb", I get only bbb and aaa-bbb (**screen 2**)
[image: screen 2]

"aaa-bbb" query gives me all my products (**screen 3**)
[image: screen 3]

And finally query "aaa_bbb" returns me only one product (**screen 4**)
[image: screen 4]

So, can you please explain me how it works and how I can change this logic? 
Specifically, I need to get only aaa-bbb product, when I search "aaa-bbb".

Did I understand correctly, Magento search engine explode my query by '-' symbol? I didn't found the confirmation of this in code, but as I see by search results it's looks like true.

Thank you for attention :)

Comment: Illia, did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Omitri, unfortunately not. But i decided to use elasticSearch engine on my project.

Comment: @Omitri Did you found a solutions for this ?

Comment: @IlliaArefyev without elastic search are you able to find solutions for this ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj, I ended up buying and installing the Mirasvit Search plugin

Answer (score 5):

Magento by default using  MySql based search.  So, it is split text on  word on by pattern  like [^a-z0-9_]. it's why aaa-bbb interpreted as "aaa bbb"

see more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: how can i change this pattern?

Comment: as I known it is possible  only with recompilation or custom parser plugin, but you can implement it with text preprocessing on Magento side